# Why does a layer of peas rise when I boil water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, fluid-statics, home-experiment

I put water and boiled them in a pot.
Then I poured in frozen peas.

What happened is some of the peas when to the bottom of the pot, and on the top there formed a layer of some of the peas (Between the two layers there was just water, I know this because I moved them with my spoon to see this happening).

I suspect that hot water rising keeps the top layer intact, but why would it form in the beginning?

Comment: I don't know why some peas float and others sink, but if there was only one layer of floating peas, it's probably because there was enough room at the surface for all of them. Maybe you could repeat the experiment in a [tall, skinny beaker](https://www.coleparmer.com/i/pyrex-1060-400-brand-1060-berzelius-tall-form-beaker-400-ml-36-cs/3451324) instead of a wide, shallow saucepan and see if you still get just one "layer" of floaters.

Comment: Btw a friend suggested the explanation that there is variance in peas buoyancy, so that some are higher and some are lower. Those that are higher rise to the top and those lower go to the bottom, and there's no reason to have something inbetween.